# Java generate next set of chronologic buttons when button is pressed in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is my first post on stackOverflow and I would love to hear about the proper etiquette for posting question on this website.

My problem in a brief couple statements: 

I want to be able to change the numbers of a label in a Java GUI by clicking a button. As I click the button the 15 labels on the screen should go from 1-15, to 16-31. And with every click the labels should generate the labels with the next 15 numbers.

Images:
Currently what happens is when I press the "Next" button is the following:

[GUI screen prior to pressing the next button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Eqr.png)

[After the next button is pressed, the screen changes to the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J49aJ.png)

The problem I face is, that after I press the next button again, the screen does not change and stays with the labels from 16-31.

Objective: To have a functional "Previous" and "Next button that orderly refreshes the GUI with the previous 15 or next 15 labels, respectively.

The following is the code for the event handlers for the "Previous" and Next" buttons:

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}                                        



int updateLabelBy = 16;
int multiplyingFactor = 1;
int sum = multiplyingFactor * updateLabelBy ;


private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //When this button is pressed, JPanel2,3,4,5 will all show the next instance of solutions 

    if (NumOfExplanations > 15) 
    {
        //Clearing out JPannels 
        jPanel1.removeAll();
        jPanel1.updateUI();
        jPanel2.removeAll();
        jPanel2.updateUI();
        jPanel3.removeAll();
        jPanel3.updateUI();
        jPanel4.removeAll();
        jPanel4.updateUI();
        jPanel5.removeAll();
        jPanel5.updateUI();



                //To update the label index numbers 

    //int multiplied = multiplyingFactor * updateLabelBy;

     for ( int i = 16; i < NumOfExplanations; i++ )
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel( "Exp " + i  );
        label.setSize(100,35);
        label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (140,40));
        label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension (100,30));
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));

        jPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        jPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 15, 0));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jPanel2.add(label);


    }

    }
    else 
        {
        final JFrame parent = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton();

        button.setText("This document only contains " + NumOfExplanations + " explanations" );
        parent.add(button);
        parent.pack();
        parent.setVisible(true);
        parent.setSize(400,200);
        parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do. To change the text displayed on a button, just do

`btn.setText( "New message" )`

Comment: I believe it is a bit more complex than that. Since 'btn.setText("message") changes all the button's labels to the same thing. The screen of the GUI can only hold 15 buttons as I have shown in the ScreenShot of the GUI above.

Comment: If all the buttons have a different name, e.g. btn1, btn2 etc. you could do btn1.setText( "message" ) which will not change all of them.

Comment: I am not manually creating buttons, I am making buttons by adding them through a 'for' loop.

Comment: OK. I'm not quite sure how to do this, but you could try `for ( int i = 1; i < 16; i++ )` and do `while i = 1 { //change button }`

Comment: Thank you for your response DalekCaan99.

Comment: Does Anyone else know the correct solution or a possible way way to make dynamic buttons??